# Runtime exec with xml / jdom

Tags: java, runtime, exec, jdom

I have written a java application that exports some data. You can choose between an excel or xml ouput. After everything is done i want the created file to automatically open.

For the Excel stuff I use JExcelAPI and to create XML I use JDOM.

I have a method openFile() that gets called last before the application quits:

```
private void openFile(File file) {

    try {
        String[] cmds = { "cmd", "/c", file.getAbsolutePath() };
        for (String s : cmds) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec(cmds);
        int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I use the Excel option the file opens just fine with the following output from openFile():

```
cmd
/c
D:\test.xls
Process exitValue: 0
```

With the XML output I won't work, although i can open the file manually just fine.

```
cmd
/c
D:\test.xml
Process exitValue: 1
```

So I guess the problem is somewhere with JDOM, because both times the application is the same, except for one method where I do the excel or xml writing. But i haven't had success until now. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If the test.xml file is valid, then it is hardly JDOM's fault that there is a problem executing the XML file..... The problem is more likely to be because you do not have the right sorts of Windows file associations with .xml files (or not the associations you expect).

What happens when you open up a cmd window: WinKey->R to open the run dialog, type cmd in the box, and then, at the 'dos' prompt type `cmd /c D:\test.xml`. What happens:

```
C:\>cmd /c C:\pnp64.xml

C:\>
```

For me it opens the XML file in internet explorer, what does it do for you?

EDIT: OK, so it opens from the commandline. Now, to debug the process, you will want to capture the standard output/error from the command. I recommend something like:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmds);
pb.redirectError(new File("C:\TEMP\process.error.log"));
pb.redirectOutput(new File("C:\TEMP\process.output.log"));
Process proc = pb.start();
int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
```

Once you have made these changes, inspect (and perhaps post here...) the contents of the error and output files.

Comment: it opens with notepad++. i tested the exec code for it alone and there it works just fine.

Comment: Updated answer with better process for getting details on process output

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have found the problem myself though.

I didn't close the FileWriter i used to create the XML document.